# Surface area of $x^2 + y^2 = 4, \quad 0 \leq z \leq 3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals, jacobian

I'm asked to calculate the surface area of 
$$x^2 + y^2 = 4, \quad 0 \leq z \leq 3$$
using the surface integral.

This is **my attempt**:

For symmetry reasons I calculate the surface area when $y>0$ and then multiply by 2.

For $y>0$ This surface can be parametrized by 
$$(x,z) : (x, \sqrt{4-x^2}, z)$$

I set 
$$r(s,t) = (2\cos{s}, 2\sin{s}, t) \quad 0 \leq s \leq 2\pi ,\quad 0 \leq t \leq 3$$
I find the normal to the surface expressed  in $(s,t)$ to be
$$(2\cos{s}, 2\sin{s},0)$$
I find the Jacobian of the transformation $(x,z) --> (s,t)$ to be $-2\sin{s}$. Using the definition of surface integral I get: 
$$\int\int\sqrt{4\sin^2{s} + 4\cos^2{s}} \cdot -2\sin{s} \quad dsdt$$
$$-4\int\int \sin{s} \quad dsdt$$
$$-4\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin{s}\quad ds \cdot \int_0^3 1\quad dt= -24$$
Now multiplying by 2 (to get both sides) I get -48 (I understand the answer can't be negative). And the answer is supposed to be $12\pi$.
**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is easier done in cylindrical coordinates. The surface has parametrization $$(2\cos(\theta),2\sin(\theta),z)$$ where $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ and $0\leq z \leq 3$. The jacobian of the transformation is then $2$. The surface integral becomes $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^32dz\,d\theta = 12\pi$$ Your jacobian seems to be the one for spherical coordinates. Double check your jacobian calculation

**Edit.** For these types of problems, I like to consider the full cylindrical coordinated map $(r,\theta,z)\mapsto (r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta),z)$. The jacobian for this matrix is standard to compute and gives $r$. If you remember $r^2 = x^2+y^2 = 4$, then you get the jacobian I computed above. Try to use these standard transformations, e.g. cylindrical, spherical, linear, etc., since it is easy to check if you have your computations correct

Comment: Thank you for brilliant answers. My Jacobian is calculated like this: $x = 2\cos{s}$ , $z = t$. I cross product the vectors $(-2\sin{s}, 0)$ and $(0,1)$ and get $-2\sin{s}$

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as accepted, if it fulfills your needs.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the way I calculate the jacobian?

Comment: I need more clarity. What is the explicit map that takes $(s,t)$ to $(x,z)$. You are supposed to take the jacobian of that map.

Comment: $x = 2\cos s, y = 2\sin s, z = t$   the jabobain  $\|(\frac {\partial x}{\partial s}, \frac {\partial y}{\partial s},\frac {\partial z}{\partial s})\times (\frac {\partial x}{\partial t}, \frac {\partial y}{\partial t},\frac {\partial z}{\partial t})\| = \|(-2\sin s, 2\cos s, 0)\times (0,0,1)\| = \|(2\cos s, 2\sin s, 0)\| = \sqrt {4\cos^2 t + 4\sin^2 t} = 2$

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are dependent variables, so my map must be between $(x,z)$ and $(s,t)$ right?

Therefore I set: 
$$x = 2*cos(s)$$
$$z = t$$
and calculate the jacobian of this transformation, like here: 
[link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+2*cos(s),+z+%3D+t+jacobian)

@DougM I am not familiar with that way of calculating the Jacobian. How can you calculate with a transformation between $(x,y,z)$ and $(s,t)$? Musn't it be a 2 --> 2 transformation?

Comment: @heuristics  $x,y,z$ describe a 2 dimensional subset of 3 dimensional space.  We need to find the surface area mapped out for a small change in $s$ and for a small change in $t.$  the differential then is  $u = (\frac {\partial x}{\partial s}, \frac {\partial y}{\partial s},\frac {\partial z}{\partial s})$ is the vector form of the differential associated with a small change in s. and $v=(\frac {\partial x}{\partial t}, \frac {\partial y}{\partial t},\frac {\partial z}{\partial t})$ is the differential for t.  And and the area between the two vectors $ = \|u\|\|v\| \sin \theta = \|u\times v\|$